# Hide NavBarButton

Tags: iphone, ios

So many posts on this and none are working. :(

So I am missing something simple, just do not know what that is.

I have dropped a Navigation Bar and a BarButtonItem on my view in IB.
I have in my .h file:
    IBBarButtonItem callHelp;
I have @property and @synthesized it

then I have connected it in my IB "control drag"

then in my viewDidLoad I have tried all of the following

```
callHelp.setHidden=TRUE;
callHelp.hidden=TRUE;
callHelp.Hidden=TRUE;
[callhelp setHidden=TRUE];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
and something I found on stack for arraying the toolbar/navbar
```

So what should I be kicking myself for missing?

Comment: Why to drop `UINavigatonBar` in IB instead of using `UINavigationController`?

Comment: well really I just want a tool bar with a button that makes a phone call.  Its not really a for nav. Just using the nave bar seemed easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added your `UINavigationBar` by InterfaceBuilder (and it's not added by `UINavigationController` using `self.navigationItem` will get you nowhere.

You have to add an `IBOutlet` for your `UINavigationBar` - the same as you did with `callHelp` button. And then in `viewDidLoad` call

```
UINavigationItem* item=[[self.navBar items] objectAtIndex:0]; //assuming navBar is your UINavigationBar IBOutlet
[item setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Using this to hide it:-(directly on item)

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

on NavBar:-

```
[self.yourNavBar.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: While this works not declaring the navbar seems to have been my biggest mistake which is why I gave Michal the check and you the vote.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your `IBBarButtonItem` inherits from `UIBarButtonItem`, it doesn't have `hidden` property.

In anyway, your post doesn't contain any information on problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove elements from a toolbar is to remove them from its item array.

In my .h, I declared the following outlet :

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar *actionToolBar;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *texteBarItem, *imageBarItem;
```

and to remove texteBar from the toolbar, you have to recreate its items, by using a temporary mutable array :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:actionToolBar.items];
NSLog(@"Number of objects : %d / description : %@", [array count], [array description]);
[array removeObject:texteBarItem];
[array removeObject:imageBarItem];
actionToolBar.items = array;
NSLog(@"Number of objects : %d / description : %@", [array count], [array description]);
```